# Spree 3.1 adjustments source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I would like to add adjustment to my order
and I want to do it at payment state in `checkout_flow`.
Can I use `Spree::Payment` as source for `Spree::Adjustment`?

Or do I have to use only `Spree::TaxRate` or a `Spree::PromotionAction` object?

I am new to Spree and maybe I misunderstood role of source in `Spree::Adjustment`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you cannot use `Spree::Payment` as a source for `Spree::Adjustment`.

What is exactly that you need to achieve? Do you want to add an Adjustment based on the payment method used by the User e.g.: charge 5 USD more/less if User pays with Check?

If you want the Adjustment to be applied after the Payment is created you can use the transition of the state machine associated with the Order.

In either case, the source of the Adjustment would be the Spree::Order object.

Comment: Exactly like you wrote... I need extra charge for payment but I already solve it with `after_create :add_payment_charge` in /models/spree/payment.rb